"a shirt in (a) (size) small"
To me, these versions sound natural and idiomatic:

I'd like this/a shirt in a small.
I'd like this/a shirt in a size small.
I'd like this/a shirt in a size 7.
Do you have this dress in a 9?
She wears a size five.

But recently I've heard from younger monolingual native English speakers (West coast US where I've spent most of my life, and online) these versions which sounded off to my ear:

a shirt in small
a shirt in size small
a dress in size 7
a dress in 9
I wear size 3.

Textual attestations can be found:

Do you have this shirt in small? (source)
Do you have this dress in size three? (source)
I wear size three (source)

Are both versions with and without the indefinite article idiomatic? Is this a new trend?

Since it's obvious that "small" or a number refers to the size, it's OK and common to leave it out.

a dress in 9 is the only one that sounds odd to my West Coast ears.

@Lambie I am not sure about your age but if you are surrounded by younger generations of native speakers as I am you will notice how amorphous their English is, presumably influenced by the prevalence of non-traditional/globalized Tiktok/Instagram English online. I don't believe you could say these are "shouldn't even have to ask" questions. You'd be surprised. An online survey showed more than half of the native-speaking high school age participants found "I am from US[sic]" valid. As for myself, all my education since secondary was received in English, in the US.
